# Qual è il senso di "cotto" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Diceria dell'untore*, di Gesualdo Bufalino, ho letto:

> Ascolta: 
>         O misero Mariano, smettila di fare il pazzo,
>   
>         e se una cosa è kaputt, convinciti ch’è kaputt...». 
>         Ridacchiò: «Non è una variante più **cotta**?».
>   E aggiunse, a voce più bassa: «Mariano kaputt, kappaò, per via di Lesbia kapò...».

C'è da dire che nel libro si racconta che questo personaggio ha recitato dei versi simili un po' prima.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "cotta" in questo passaggio? Tra le diverse accezioni dell'aggettivo "cotto" che ho trovato nei dizionari, non riesco a vedere a quale corrisponda l'uso che se ne fa nel testo precedente.

Comment: Ho la netta impressione che sia un refuso. Forse “colta”?

Comment: @egreg: Io ho l'edizione Bompiani, ma poi ho trovato  [questa versione edita da Einaudi](https://www.scribd.com/doc/161590647/Diceria-Dell-Untore-Gesualdo-Bufalino) nella quale appare la stessa parola, cioè, "cotta".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I due versi riecheggiano l’apertura del carme 8 di Catullo («Miser Catulle desinas ineptire / et quod vides perisse perditum ducas»), in una versione più “forte” e “militare” (in questo senso penso si possa intendere “cotta”), in cui Lesbia (la donna amata dal poeta Catullo e che tanto lo faceva soffrire) è un kapò e la fine di Mariano è decretata da un “kaputt” (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/kaputt/).